# Android Room Database app is crashing without showing any error

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to perform very basic insert and select * operations using Room database library with android java. But when i do execute the query with button press then my application is get crashed without showing any error in the logcat.

Database row is inserted only when i do reinstall the app and again pressing insert or select * button app get crashed. I'm new in this library please guide me correct code.

**@Entity**

```
public class Users {

    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
    public String uname;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastname")
    public String lname;

    public Users(String uname, String lname) {
        this.uname = uname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
}
```

**@Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface UsersDao{
    @Query("select * from Users")
    List<Users>getUsers();

    @Insert
    void insertUser(Users user);
}
```

**@Database**

```
@Database(entities = {Users.class},version = 1)
public abstract class UsersDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UsersDao usersDao();
}
```

**Calling methods onCreate()**

```
UsersDatabase db= Room.databaseBuilder(Practice.this,UsersDatabase.class,
                "Users").build();
        UsersDao dao=db.usersDao();

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dao.insertUser(new Users("George","Pal"));
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<>();
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        List<Users> users=dao.getUsers();
                        for(Users u: users)
                            data.add(u.uname+", "+u.lname);
                        ArrayAdapter<String > adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(Practice.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

**Dependencies**

```
def roomVersion = "2.4.0"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

**My config**

- Real device api 30
- Arctic fox

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Threads. I have replaced Threads with AsyncTask.